# Can someone explain how memory is allocated to double pointer in the following code

Tags: c, pointers

Please explain in the below qsort standard code, why address of argv and
argv[ 0 ] are different.
I am a newbie in c. Trying to understand double pointers concept.

```
    static int compare( void const * p1, void const *p2 )
    {
      return strcmp( * ( char * const*  )p1, * ( char * const * )p2 );
     }

     int main( int arg, char **argv )
      {
        if( arg < 2 )
          {
            fprintf( stderr, "arguments should be more than 1" );
            exit( 0 );
           }
        printf( "\n address of argv %p", &argv );
        printf( "\n address of argv[ 0 ] %p", &argv[ 0 ] );
        printf( "\n address of argv[ 1 ] %p", &argv[ 1 ] );
        printf( "\n address of argv[ 2 ] %p", &argv[ 2 ] );
        printf( "\n Value of argv[ 0 ] %p %s", argv[ 0 ], argv[ 0 ] );
        printf( "\n Value of argv[ 1 ] %p %s", argv[ 1 ], argv[ 1 ] );
        printf( "\n Value of argv[ 2 ] %p %s \n ", argv[ 2 ], argv[ 2 
                 ]  );

        qsort( &argv[ 1 ], arg - 1, sizeof( char* ), compare );
         int j;  
         for( j = 1; j < arg; j++ )
          {
             puts( argv[ j ] );
             printf( "\n" );
             }
           return 0;
          }
```

Output:
./a.out ramya usha

```
address of argv 0x7ffede23dde0   
address of argv[ 0 ] 0x7ffede23dee8
address of argv[ 1 ] 0x7ffede23def0
address of argv[ 2 ] 0x7ffede23def8
Value of argv[ 0 ] 0x7ffede23e2f0 ./a.out
Value of argv[ 1 ] 0x7ffede23e2f8 ramya
Value of argv[ 2 ] 0x7ffede23e2fe usha


Why address of argv is '0x7ffede23dde0' whereas argv[ 0 ] it is
    0x7ffede23dee8
```

Comment: 1) Not very important but the convention for `main` is `int args`  instead of `int arg`.  2) Use `(void *)object`  with `%p` specifier in `printf` 3) `return strcmp( * ( char * const*  )p1, * ( char * const * )p2 );` --> `return strcmp( (char *)p1, ( char *)p2 );`

Comment: @KeineLust ITYM the convention is "int argc, char *argv[]"

Comment: @BjornA. you are right!!

Comment: k. Thanks. I got this doubt when I saw the example for use of qsort in qsort man page

Answer (score 1):

Well why should it be same? (OP asked *why address of argv and argv[ 0 ] are different.*)

`main()` is a function. Now an array of pointers to it - the array decayed to the pointer to the first element. And now the local variable `argv` contains that value. (that pointer value).

You print it. And then now you access the first element's address. That address is being printed. Now the main thing the content of it, it is the decayed pointer value of the char array.

These three different addresses you have printed. And yes they are different. It is not like they are the same thing with different syntactic sugar. No more suprises.

To give you a more clear idea - think this `&argv[0]` is nothing but the same as `argv`. And no suprise, it will be different from `&argv`.

Also printing the pointer should be `void*` casted. Also enable compiler warnings you will see some more errors/warnings check them.

Answer (score 0):

As @coderredoc pointed out, when you use `&argv`, you're asking for the location of the local variable `argv`, which has nothing whatsoever to do with the contents of the argument array.

If you'll devote some careful attention to the output of your program, this is what it is telling you (I've shortened the memory addresses for the sake of brevity):

```
location          variable          value

0xdde0            argv              0xdee8    
0xdee8            argv[0]           0xe2f0   
0xdef0            argv[1]           0xe2f8
0xdef8            argv[2]           0xe2fe
.
.
0xe2f0            argv[0][0]        '.'  => ./a.out\0
0xe2f8            argv[1][0]        'r'  => ramya\0   
0xe2fe            argv[2][0]        'u'  => usha\0
```

The fact that `argv` is a double pointer does *not* change the fact that it is still a *pointer*. Its value is the location of some other value.

The main thing to do when dealing with pointers is to *pay attention*. When you have a pointer variable, whether it's a single, double, or triple pointer (if you have more than that, then you have other more serious problems), you have to keep in mind *exactly* what you want when you use the `*` or the `&` operators, and *exactly* what you're getting when you do.

Comment: I got confused because while dealing with char arrays, like a[ 5 ]., address of   &a and &a [ 0 ] are same. And Iam unable to figure out with double pointer.  Thanks alot for explaining with memory lay out.